# How to Set Default Version of Python to 3.x vs 2.7 on Mac OSX?

Tags: python, django, macos

I am attempting to install django framework using `pip install -e django/`, however, it requires Python 3.5+. Mac OSX by default comes with Python 2.7 so I have installed Python 3.6.5 from the python website.

I have confirmed the latest version of Python is installed through `python3` .

I am still unable to install Django likely because Python 2.7 is also installed and seen first by pip.

Is it necessary to remove Python 2.7 from my system or can I modify `PYTHON_HOME` to achieve what I would like to do?

Comment: Try pip3 install -e django

Comment: @AriK great, thanks.

Comment: It is not only not necessary to remove the preinstalled Python 2.7, it's a very bad idea. Apple put it in the `/System` directory, which you're not supposed to touch on pain of breaking core parts of the macOS userland or making upgrades fail.

Comment: However, Apple's Python doesn't come with `pip`, and it's a good idea to not install `pip` (or anything else) for it if you don't plan to use it—just leave it there untouched for macOS. Also, python.org (and Homebrew) Python 3.6 usually doesn't require `sudo pip`, but Apple Python 2.7 does, so avoid ever using `sudo pip` and if you accidentally use the wrong one, you'll get permission errors that should remind you that you wanted `pip3` or `python3 -m pip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install to python 3 using

```
pip3 install django

python3 -m pip install django
```

As abarnert says in the comments, you shouldn't remove the Python 2.7 installation or try to set Python 3 to be the default.

It's good practice to use a virtual environment. Since you're using Python 3 you could use [pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/). Once the Python 3 virtual environment is activated, `python` will use the python 3 from the virtual environment.